# How to query the waiting validators in past eras?

Tags: validator, session, pallet-staking

Getting the current active validators could be done. Also getting the past Active validators also can be queried using EraStakers in staking pallet. How to query waiting validators by Era Index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native API available for this purpose.

The set of waiting validators can be obtained by subtracting the active validators from the `Staking::Validators` set.

It's important to note that an era consists of multiple blocks. Some validators may choose to `chill` at any block within the era. Therefore, you need to specify which block you want to use. If you have a specific block hash in mind, simply pass it as a parameter to the `query_at` field of `Staking::Validators`.

Once you have both sets - validators and active validators - you can subtract them.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @AurevoirXavier answer, [API Sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) exposes the endpoint `pallets/staking/Validators` which returns a list of all validators addresses and their corresponding status which can be either active or waiting. It will also return a list of active validators that will not be part of the next era for staking. If you are running API Sidecar against an archive node, you can do this query at any past height.